# Version ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm starting with DotNet Core, and when I create my first project by choosing the option "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)" in the next screen I only see the versions below

- ASP.NET Core 1.0
- ASP.NET Core 1.1

However I have already installed the SDK (dotnet-sdk-2.1.402-win-x64), but this version 2.1 does not appear for me to choose, follow the image for better visualization.

[image]

Entering the prompt the version is apparently installed.

[image]

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Visual Studio 2017 (15.8) is supposed to have .NET Core 2.1.4 out of the box. https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/2323#issuecomment-396665345

Comment: Please make sure you use Visual Studio 2017 Update 3 or higher  Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 and all the updates.

Version 1.0, 1.1 and 2.1 are very different, I would recommend not even using 1.0 and 1.1 and try and setup for 2.1.

Comment: Did an update to Visual Studio and it worked.  Thanks